# Access to module from view template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following module defined in /models/concerns:

```
module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def self.bar
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

I can access `Foo.bar` in the console.

How should I do to be able to acces `Foo.bar` in a view template?

Comment: it looks like you actually want to use a view helper

Comment: If you want to use it in the view,put that in the `application_helper.rb` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference in your template. just use `Foo.bar` as you have in the console.

If you have tried that and you are having problems with it, please let us know the specific error message you are getting, and what line of code is failing

Comment: The problem was that I had `puts`, removing that was what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in the `view`,put that in the `application_helper.rb` file.Try it like this

```
#application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def bar
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

And in the view,just call it as

```
<%= bar %>
```